# SQL Equivalent of IN with odata

Tags: odata

I have a collection I am querying using OData syntax. Each of the documents that I am querying looks like this:

```
{
  id:1,
  name:'test 1',
  storeId: 1
}
```

Each document can belong to one of 100 stores. I need to get the documents that belong to a specified collection of stores. In SQL, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  [Document] d
WHERE
  d.[storeId] IN (5, 22, 31, 19, 75)
```

I think with OData, I need to do something like this:

```
http://services.odata.org/V4/MyService/Documents?$format=application/json;odata.metadata=full&$filter=storeId [something goes here]
```

I'm not sure what to put in the `[something goes here]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid ODATA does not have a parallel to SQL IN as of now. (https://issues.oasis-open.org/browse/ODATA-556) . You might need to do something like this:

```
$filter=(storeID eq 5) or (storeID eq 22) or (storeID eq 31) or (storeID eq 19) or (storeID eq 75)
```

You can probably loop over the array to form the ODATA query.

Hope this helps you.